# Buildozer error while compiling apk - pip ssl

Tags: ssl, pip, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to compile a simple program into an apk for Android with Buildozer but have run into the following problem. Can you please help? I tried upgrading pip but that didn't help:python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

So, I reverted back to the original pip version.

Installed Cython separately: pip3 install Cython

But the same issue persists. I am at a loss. :-(

Command: buildozer android debug

```
RAN: /bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install Cython'
STDOUT:
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

How can I fix this?

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

Comment: I still have this problem on macos. tried many versions of openssl but nothing ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recent bug, you need to install libssl-dev using `apt install libssl-dev`

Then you might also want to clean your buildozer directory by running `rm -rf .buildozer` in the directory that contains your buildozer.spec file.

That should do it!

Comment: Hi!. Thanks for your suggestion. That worked. I got past that step but got stuck here: "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hostpython2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for hostpython2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))"
hostpython3 is already installed. Why is buildozer looking for hostpython2?

Comment: @ShoumikDas do you specify python2 in your buildozer.spec file anywhere?

Comment: No. Python2 is not specified anywhere in the spec file.